# Keycloak configuration in application.properties for spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I have given all the roles,permissions,resources and policies in key cloak console.But why do I have to give roles and resources again in application.properties.If i don't give those in application.properties,all the resources are accessible.So,what actually do i have to mention in application.properties.

[evaluation in keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn6vp.png)

[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJvct.png)

[permissions for resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwzaa.png)

is it necessary to give keycloak.json in application? what are all the things to be configured in application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to keycloak.json.But you have to use spring boot version 2.0 and above.That will work.